# How to put multiple plots with inner plots in a M x N layout without messing up the par()s?

Tags: r, for-loop, plot, layout, par

I make a plot within a plot.

(I use `curve()` here for simplicity, but this also refers to `plot()`.)

```
curve(exp(x), 0, 1, col=4)
.op <- par(
  fig=c(grconvertX(c(.05, .4), to='ndc'),
        grconvertY(c(2, 2.75), to='ndc')),
  mar=c(1, 1, 1, 1),
  new=TRUE
)
curve(sin(x), 0, 2*pi)
par(.op)
```

[image]

Repeating this in a `for` loop basically works well. However, when I try use a 2x2 `layout`, the figures are spread over four different plots instead of being shown on one.

```
layout(matrix(1:4, 2, 2))
for (i in 1:4) {
  curve(exp(x), 0, 1, col=4)
  .op <- par(
    fig=c(grconvertX(c(.05, .3), to='ndc'),
          grconvertY(c(2, 2.75), to='ndc')),
    mar=c(1, 1, 1, 1),
    new=TRUE
  )
  curve(sin(x), 0, 2*pi)
  par(.op)
}
```

For some reason the inner `par` messes up the outer one. I also tried to `op <- par(mfrow=); ... par(op)` instead of `layout`, but with same result.

How can I fix that?

Comment: In the help page for `layout`, there is a warning: "These functions are totally incompatible with the other mechanisms for arranging plots on a device: par(mfrow), par(mfcol) and split.screen.".

Comment: @Edward Thx for pointing out that warning, have a solution?

Comment: I think using `screen` will work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using `screen` instead.

```
split.screen(c(2,2))
for (i in 1:4) {
  screen(i)
  curve(exp(x), 0, 1, col=4)
  title(paste("i=",i))

  .op <- par(
    fig=c(grconvertX(c(.05, .3), to='ndc'),
          grconvertY(c(2, 2.75), to='ndc')),
    mar=c(1, 1, 1, 1),
    new=TRUE
  )
  curve(sin(x), 0, 2*pi)
  par(.op)
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks this is great. With tips from [@Robert Hacken
's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76680789/6574038) I was able to refine this to also get a readable inner plot as well as axes ticks. Please see [my own answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76693952/6574038).

Answer (score 2):

If you want to stick to using `layout` (sort of), you can first create a series of empty plots to find the coordinates for the layout regions. Then, not relying on `layout` anymore, you can define them again with `par(fig=...)` which will allow you to draw the inner plots without things getting messed up.

```r
layout(matrix(1:4, 2, 2))
# store coordinates of layout regions
figs <- sapply(1:4, \(i) {
  frame()
  par('fig')
})
# to overwrite the empty plots
par(new=T)

for (i in 1:4) {
  
  # set figure region to the current layout window
  par(fig = figs[, i])
  
  curve(exp(x), 0, 1, col=4)
  .op <- par(
    fig=c(grconvertX(c(.05, .3), to='ndc'),
          grconvertY(c(2, 2.75), to='ndc')),
    mar=c(1, 1, 1, 1),
    new=TRUE
  )
  curve(sin(x), 0, 2*pi)
  par(.op)
  par(new=T)
}
```

[image: using layout]

Comment: This is also great, thx. However, as commented under _@Edward_'s answer it's really important that the inner plot won't be squeezed like in the current solutions. I think `layout` or `par` somehow care for that.

Comment: If you try e.g. `layout(matrix(1:9, 3))` and `for (i in 1:9)` you see what I mean, it doesn't scale.

Comment: @jay.sf I am not sure I understand what you mean. The inner plot gets squeezed because its region specified by `par('fig')` has to contain its margins. However, these margins are relative to font size so they will always take up the same absolute amount of space, thus decreasing the space available for the plot itself. If you want the plots in layout to look the same as when you have just one plot, you have to decrease font size. E.g., for the 2x2 case, `par(cex=.5)` would do the job.

Comment: Interesting, didn't know about the dynamics of the margins! The `par(cex=.5)` makes indeed nice inner/outer plots. I create 6x7 PDFs, can you see a way to get the tick labels readable w/o messing around too much with `axis/mtext`? I use global `.cex=3; curve(., cex.axis=.cex)` and `par(cex=.cex*.1)` for the inner guy to get no margin errors.

Comment: I am afraid I would need to know more details to help you with the tick labels but maybe you will really have to use something along the lines of `axis`/`mtext`.

Comment: Thanks again for your valuable hints. It might indeed be better to use `split.screen()` from [@Edward's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76678226/6574038) which I finally used. I was able to refine this to also get a readable inner plot as well as axes ticks. Please see [my own answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76693952/6574038).

Answer (score 2):

Here's how I combined the insights from the two answers in a function `plot_fun()`. From [@Edward](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76678226/6574038) I take `split.screen`, and from [@Robert Hacken](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76680789/6574038) the fact that `curve` (or `plot` respectively) produces margins relative to the font size that we may manipulate using `cex`.

```
plot_fun <- \(spl, .cex=3, iadj=0) {
  scr <- split.screen(spl)
  for (i in scr) {
    screen(i)
    par(mar=c(5, 6, 4, 3) + .1)
    curve(exp(x), 0, 1, col=4, cex.axis=.cex, cex.lab=.cex)
    .op <- par(
      fig=c(grconvertX(c(.1, .4), to='ndc'),
            grconvertY(c(2 + iadj, 2.75), to='ndc')),
      mar=c(1, 1, 1, 1),
      cex=.cex*.1,
      new=TRUE
    )
    curve(sin(x), 0, 2*pi, cex.axis=.cex*3)
    par(.op)
  }
  close.screen(all.screens=TRUE)
}
    

f <- 4  ## appears to work fine with the two versions below

pdf("tmp/p1.pdf", 16*f, 9*f)
plot_fun(spl=c(6, 7))
dev.off()
```

[image]

```
pdf("tmp/p1.pdf", 16*f, 9*f)
plot_fun(spl=c(2, 3), iadj=.2)
dev.off()
```

[image]

If we wish cleaner tick labels on the axes for publishing or so, we may still use `curve(., axes=FALSE)` and mess around with `axis()` and `mtext()`, but this already gives an acceptable result for analyses without great effort.

If your device gets messed up during setup and gives weird results, use `graphics.off()` and `close.screen(all.screens=TRUE)` to reset the device.